# What's the safest way to define short function name aliases in C++?

Tags: c++, function, macros, alias, c-preprocessor

Suppose I have a class `Utility` in a file `utility.h`:

```
class Utility {
public:
    static double longDescriptiveName(double x) { return x + 42; }
};
```

And then I find that I use the function `longDescriptiveName(...)` a LOT. So like an irresponsible C++ programmer that I am when I've had too much coffee, I create a new file `utilitymacros.h` and add the following there:

```
#define ldn Utility::longDescriptiveName
```

Now I include `"utilitymacros.h"` in any `*.cpp` where I use `ldn(...)` and my heart is filled with joy over how much more convinient it is to type 3 letters vs 28.

**Question:** Is there a safer (more proper) way of doing this than with `#define`?

I've noticed that I have to include "utilitymacros.h" after including boost headers, which I obviously don't like because it's a sign of clashes (though the Boost errors I get are not very clear as to what the clash is).

**Clarification 1: On Code Readability**

In case you might say that this negatively affects code readability, I assure you it does not, because it's a small set of functions that are used A LOT. An example that is widely know is `stoi` for `stringToInteger`. Another is `pdf` for `probabilityDensityFunction`, etc. So if I want to do the following, `stoi` is more readable in my opinion:

```
int x = stoi(a) + stoi(b) + stoi(c) + stoi(d);
```

Than:

```
int x = Utility::stringToInteger(a) + Utility::stringToInteger(b)
        + Utility::stringToInteger(c) + Utility::stringToInteger(d);
```

Or:

```
int x = Utility::stringToInteger(a);
x += Utility::stringToInteger(b);
x += Utility::stringToInteger(c);
x += Utility::stringToInteger(d);
```

**Clarification 2: Editor Macro**

I use Emacs as my IDE of choice and a Kinesis keyboard so you KNOW I use a ton of keyboard macros, custom keyboard shortcuts, as well as actually modifying what I see in the editor vs what's actually stored in the h/cpp file. But still, I feel like the simplicity and visual readability (as argued above) of using a function abbreviation in a few select cases really is the result I'm looking for (this is certainly subject to a degree).

Comment: I don't really think this is a good idea, since it harms code readability.

Comment: I would assume that `pdf` was a file format, and be *really* confused. Characters are free and you don't save the environment by not using them.

Comment: Well, maybe short names are readable for YOU, but it's hard for others, even (or especially) when they are used everywhere. On my old there were alot of 3 character function names and it was one of many reasons why I quit there: The code was an unreadable mess. Sure, not only because of the function and variable names, but it was a part of it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Instead of macro, you could write `inline` function that forwards the call to the actual function:

```
inline double ldn(double x)
{
   return Utility::longDescriptiveName(x);
}
```

That is certainly *safer* than macro.

Comment: +1 definitely inline functions are safer as there type checking and i think it is recommended to be used (C++ style) instead of #define (C style and less safe). Aside note: unlike Macros inline lacks using any data type which is accomplished by using templates with inline !

Comment: @Nawaz, I'm assuming that the inline function is not part of class `Utility`, correct? In that case, would you suggest to put the inline definition in the same header as `utility.h` or create a separate header for them like `utilityhelpers.h`?

Comment: @LexFridman: Yes. It is outside the class `Utility`. You can put it in the same header, but outside the class. It depends on you.

Answer (score 7):

You could use a function reference:

```
double (&ldn)(double) = Utility::longDescriptiveName;
```

Comment: Should not it be `static double (&ldn)(double) = ...`?

Comment: In C++11, `auto &&ldn = Utility::longDescriptiveName;` which is very idiomatic. What's the advantage of `static` in any case?

Comment: @Potatoswatter: It is in a header file; `static` is used to avoid multiple-definition error.

Comment: @Nawaz `static` is used to define multiple different objects with the same name. It might be better to use `extern`. Anyway, an unnamed namespace is generally preferred.

Comment: Using a function reference may have an impact on the ability of the function calls to be inlined.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: `static` would work as fine; doesn't matter if it defines multiple because its not modifying it.

Comment: @jogojapan: I was thinking the same, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 3):

How about configuring a snippit/macro/similar thing in your text editor?  This way you only have to type ldn or something like that and the code doesn't have to run through the preprocessor risking difficult to find bugs later.

Comment: Plus, it will be comprehensible after being typed out.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this helps, but I think part of the problem may be the use of overly general namespaces (or class names, in this case), such as `Utility`.

If instead of `Utility::stringToInteger`, we had

```
namespace utility {
  namespace type_conversion {
    namespace string {
      int to_int(const std::string &s);
    }
  }
}
```

Then the function could locally be used like this:

```
void local_function()
{
  using namespace utility::type_conversion::string;

  int sum = to_int(a) + to_int(b) + to_int(c) + to_int(d);
}
```

Analogously, if classes/structs and static functions are used (and there can be good reasons for this), we have something like

```
strut utility {
  struct type_conversion {
    struct string {
      static int to_int(const std::string &s);
    };
  };
};
```

and the local function would look something like this:

```
void local_function()
{
  typedef utility::type_conversion::string str;

  int sum = str::to_int(a) + str::to_int(b)
              + str::to_int(c) + str::to_int(d);
}
```

I realize I am not telling you anything about syntax you didn't know already; it's more a reminder of the fact that the organization and structure of namespaces and classes itself plays an important role in making code more readable (and writable).

Answer (score 2):

One alternative is to rename your function and put it in a namespace instead of a class, since it is static anyway. `utility.h` becomes

```
namespace Utility {
    // long descriptive comment
    inline double ldn(double x) { return x + 42; }
}
```

Then you can put `using namespace Utility;` in your client code.

I know there are lots of style guides out there saying short names are a bad thing, but I don't see the point of obeying some style and then circumventing it.

Answer (score -1):

You can use alias template (since C++11).

```
  using shortName = my::complicate::function::name;
```

Comment: can just use class name, but not function name