# #define part of a function's name

Tags: c++, function, variables

In C++ is it possible to do something like this:

```
#define PREFIX "i_have_a_very_long_method_name_"

void PREFIX foo() {

}
```

Instead of this:

```
void i_have_a_very_long_method_name_foo() {

}
```

?

Comment: This sounds like a job for namespaces, not preprocessor abuse.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14092229/whats-the-safest-way-to-define-short-function-name-aliases-in-c